# Taking negative of the minimum negative number, C/C++

Tags: math, arithmetic-expressions

I have ran into a peculiar situation:

```
void f(signed int8 Var1) {

   if ( Var1 < 0 ) 
      Var1 = -Var1;
   
   /// at this point I'm expecting Var1 to be >= 0
   /// and it works, unless we call f(-128).
   /// for -128 there is no corresponding positive number that 
   /// signed int8 can hold, and (-Var1) results in the same -128.
}
```

I ran into this while working on an embedded code, but I tested this and works the same funny way on Windows as well.

For now I added this to the code:

```
if (Var1 == -128)
   Var1 = 127;
```

I'm wondering if there is better way of dealing with this.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to deal with it. But you have not said what you want to do, so we cannot tell you what ways there are. Do you want to store the value? Put it in an unsigned 8-bit integer or any wider integer. Do you want to work with the value? Use an `int`. Or, instead of making all numbers positive (or zero), make them negative and adjust all the work with the number to expect that.

Comment: I'm simply calculating |Var1|, or in other words abs(Var1). You are right, moving it into a wider int and doing || there will work correctly. But not entirely, I will still need the saturation check:
This is what I need to calculate: int16_t Var2 = abs(Var1)*256; So even if I do int16_t Var2 = Var1; Var2 = abs(Var2); Var2 *=256; I will still end up with a negative number!

Answer (score 0):

the point is the result of |-128| cannot be expressed in an 8 bit signed integer. So what do you want to do in that case? One possibility is to not overwrite var1 but to have a working internal variable thats unsigned 8 bit. That can always hold the result of |u8|

I dont know if thats really a solution because you have not explained what happens next in f.

Here is my suggestion

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdint.h>
   
   void f(int8_t Val1){
     uint8_t abs  ;
     if (Val1 < 0){
       abs = -Val1;
     } else{
       abs = Val1;
    }
     printf("i=%d o=%u\n", Val1, abs);
   }
   int main()
   {
     f(1);
     f(-4);
     f(-128);
   }
```

output

```
i=1 o=1
i=-4 o=4
i=-128 o=128
```

Comment: I understand that, naturally. I'm ok with getting +127 for the abs(-128)

Comment: @Kostja then whats the question?

Comment: A better way to get a guaranteed positive number out of a negative. Some suggested to me using  library provided abs(), but at list on VCC++ it works exactly the same.

Comment: @Kostja see edit

Comment: I think that works for me!